# Absolute div does not scroll with page

Tags: css, html, position, absolute

From the fiddle below, I am trying to make the 'inner-navigation' div absolutely positioned so it stays fixed within the 'compare-display' box. The problem I am having is that when you scroll, the 'inner-navigation' div does not stay fixed. How can I remedy this problem?

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9eZ/

HTML Code

```
<div class="compare-display">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="source-compare col-50">
            <div class="page"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-compare">
            <div class="inner-navigation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="target-compare col-50">
            <div class="page"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.table > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.table > .col-50 {
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
}
.compare-display {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
.compare-display .navigation-compare {
    min-width: 50px;
    background: blue;

}
.compare-display .page {
    margin: 20px;
    height: 500px;
    background: orange;
}
.compare-display .inner-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap a fixed div around '.compare-display' and remove the relative position from '.compare-display'.

Like so:

[jsfiddle.net/Cd9eZ/4](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9eZ/4)

```
.compare-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
}

.compare-display {
    /*position: relative;*/
}

<div class="compare-wrapper">
    <div class="compare-display">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Think you want `position:fixed` rather than `position:absolute`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9eZ/2/)

[CSS Position Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: I want it to be fixed relative to the '.compare-display' div. Fixed pushes it out of the div and makes it relative to the document.

Comment: Hmm.. that's an interesting thought. Unfortunately I don't there's a CSS solution to reflect your idea. Since the `inner-navigation` div is part of the HTML content of its parent, you can only position it relative to the content inside of its parent. In this case `compare-display` class has overflow, so all of its relative content will be scrollable.

Comment: You could also go down a JavaScript route with this. Is there any particular behavior brought on by the `position:fixed` property that is undesired?

Comment: The only thing that I find undesirable about position fixed is that you would have to know what the position offset of '.compare-display' div is to the document itself. So if it's positioned 200px from the top, you have to use javascript to offset the fixed div so it sits exactly on top of '.compare-display'. I was just hoping to be able to do that without javascript. But as you explained in your comment, that seems to be not possible. Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you update your answer that explains why this is not possibile with CSS alone? And maybe provide the javascript solution that will make this work with a fixed position so other people who are also looking to do the same thing can easily find the answer

Comment: I just figured out how to do it with CSS alone

Comment: Wrap a fixed div around 'compare-display' and remove the relative position from compare 'compare-display'. Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9eZ/4/

Comment: Due to my reputation, I can't answer the question for the next 6 hours X_X

Comment: Ah good call using the fixed position on the wrapper element! I'll be sure to vote up your answer when you can submit it. =)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the help! Answer posted, and now I just have to wait 24hrs to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Was this what you intended?

http://jsfiddle.net/Cd9eZ/3/

```
 .compare-display .inner-navigation {
   **position: fixed;**
   width: 50px;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: red;
 }
```

If you want the navigation affixed to the window, absolute will not work. Absolute does not remove the element from the page flow, so scrolling will always move an absolutely positioned element because the frame of reference is the *page* itself, and not the *window*.

Fixed elements are removed from the page flow entirely and are rooted to the window space itself.

Comment: That is not what I intended. I want it to stay absolutely positioned relative to the '.compare-display' div. However, I think you have partially answered my question. Which is that it is not possible to have the absolutely positioned div scroll with the scrollbar.